# Bootstrap menu is not collapsed by default in mobile view

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to implement a vertical navigation with twitter bootstrap 3.0 that collapses automatically.

The basics work (window size small = menu at the top like it should be), but the problem is that it is not collapsed as it is if I use the default navbar features in bootstrap.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <a href="<g:createLink uri="/" absolute="true" />">BABSI</a>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#sidebar">TOOGLE

                    Toggle navigation
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <header id="sidebar" class="col-md-2 collapse">

                <div class="row">

                                    <!-- generates ul structure -->
                    <nav:primary class="nav navbar-inverse nav-stacked" />
                </div>
            </header>
            <section id="content" class="col-md-10">
                <div class="row"></div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <g:layoutTitle />
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <g:layoutBody />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `.navbar-collapse` class in your nav since that's the one that is set up to collapse at the given breakpoint.

I made some changes in your markup to accommodate that and also added a `.navbar` container so you can easily use the `.navbar-toggle` class on the button:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-brand"> 
            <a href="#">BABSI</a>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebar .navbar-collapse"> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <header id="sidebar" class="col-md-2">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <!-- generates ul structure -->
                <nav:primary class="nav navbar-inverse nav-stacked" />
            </div>
        </header>
        <section id="content" class="col-md-10">
            <div class="row"></div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <g:layoutTitle />
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <g:layoutBody />
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

To remove unwanted styles and since you're not using the default navbar-collapse structure you need to add this to your CSS

```
//remove background and border from navbar
.navbar-default{
    background: none;
    border: 0;
}
.navbar-collapse{
    padding: 0;
}

//override width:auto of navbar-collapse
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-collapse {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Here's a **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkgxw/11/show/)** with the changes

Comment: does not work, first it applies some css styles I don't want (I can handle that), but also breaks the whole collapsing. The list element collapses (slide from bottom to top), and immediatly snaps back as it were before the animation...

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<script>
    $('.navbar-collapse a').click(function(){
        $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
    });
</script>
```