# Bootstrap 3 sidebar menu doesn't toggle/expand (using Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a sidebar menu using the following template in Wordpress: http://www.bootply.com/88026

The problem: the menu doesn't toggle on smaller screens. You can see the toggle button but it doesn't do anything. Not sure what's going on.

I'm using the bootstrap basic theme for wordpress.

I've added the JS from the template via a plugin called Scripts n Styles and when I check the page source, it's in the header.

When I change the button (in header below) to the following, it toggles the main content, so not quite right (I also tried various other combinations, to no avail):

`<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"   data-target=".row-offcanvas-left">`

This is my header.php:

```
<div class="page-container">

<!-- top navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".sidebar-nav">
                     <span class="sr-only"><?php _e('Toggle navigation', 'bootstrap-basic'); ?></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand site-title" href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name', 'display')); ?>" rel="home"> title</a>

    </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">

    <!-- sidebar -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
                <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'nav', 'walker' => new BootstrapBasicMyWalkerNavMenu())); ?>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
padding-top: 51px;
}
.text-center {
padding-top: 20px;
}
.col-xs-12 {
background-color: #fff;
}
#sidebar {
height: 100%;
padding-right: 0;
padding-top: 60px;
}
#sidebar .nav {
width: 95%;
}
#sidebar li {
border-right: 0px #f2f2f2 solid;
}

/* collapsed sidebar styles */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.row-offcanvas {
position: relative;
-webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
.row-offcanvas-right
.sidebar-offcanvas {
 right: -41.6%;
}

.row-offcanvas-left
.sidebar-offcanvas {
left: -41.6%;
}
.row-offcanvas-right.active {
right: 41.6%;
}
.row-offcanvas-left.active {
 left: 41.6%;
}
.sidebar-offcanvas {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 41.6%;
}
#sidebar {
padding-top:0;
}
}
```

Comment: You are missing some vital CSS rules. Such as `.collapse` and several others.

Comment: I just used what's in the example, where it's working. The bootstrap CSS is linked as well via the theme

Comment: On the link it works: http://imgur.com/fmHfwHc , maybe cache ?

Comment: cleared cache, still not working. Maybe it's something about the theme and using wp walker nav menu. I'll try hard coding the menu to see if it works. edit: nope, hard coding doesn't work either - copied the exact html and css from the example

Comment: I solved the issue by basing my menu on this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722596/bootstrap-menu-is-not-collapsed-by-default-in-mobile-view